# Having difficulties writing the right Regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match item number in the following text:

```
User Number 1 will probably like movie ID: RecommendedItem[item:557, value:7.32173]the most!
```

Here is what I tried:

```
 myfile = open('result.txt', 'r')

 for line in myfile:
  m = re.search('(?<=RecommendedItem\[item:).+,', line)
  print m
```

However, this is giving me an error:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106e79168>
```

I was wondering what might be wrong with the look behind assertion...(Lookbehind assertions don't seem to work on regexpal.com, even something as simple as (?<=a)b is highlighted in red there)

Comment: `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106e79168>` is not an error, it means you found a match. If it returned `None` you would have no match.

Comment: Oh! How exactly do I get the item number in the variable 'm'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't an error! The result of `re.search` is a MatchObject. Which contains the matches inside it, these are accessed via `MatchObject.group(groupNumber,...)` (there other ways, such as groups() etc..) as explained here: [group](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group). You would want a regex as follows to do what you ask:

```
import re
t = "User Number 1 will probably like movie ID: RecommendedItem[item:557, value:7.32173]the most!"
itemNumber = re.search(r'(?<=RecommendedItem\[item:)(\d+)',t)
print(itemNumber.group(0))
```

Or alternatively, using a named group:

```
import re
t = "User Number 1 will probably like movie ID: RecommendedItem[item:557, value:7.32173]the most!"
itemNumber = re.search(r'(?<=RecommendedItem\[item:)(?P<itemNumber>\d+)',t)
print(itemNumber.groupdict()["itemNumber"]) #note using groupdict() not group()
```

Producing

```
>>> 
557
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! I hadn't come across the group function before. Any idea why regexpal.com doesn't work with look behinds? That site is amazing otherwise.

Comment: The syntax is different for different regex flavours. regexpal is for the **JavaScript** regex style, python's is 'quite' different.

Answer (score 1):

To get the matching part of your regexp you should use

```
if m:
    print line[m.start():m.end()]
```

Or you may use `re.findall` function that returns a list of matches:

```
m = re.findall('(?<=RecommendedItem\[item:).+,', line))
if m:
    print m[0]
```

You may also want to modify your regexp a bit not to have comma at the end: `'(?<=RecommendedItem\[item:)\d+`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I forgot the comma. It's actually better to just use \d+

Answer (score 1):

To get the item number out of the match object try printing m.groups().

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects for other things you can do with 'm'